# How can I change zero matrix to one, according to the predetermined row and column in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Now, I have 12x18 of zero matrix :

```
zero = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

and I struck on how to change 0 to 1 in row from this list

```
newArr2 = [[11, 17], 0, [5, 6], [13], [4], [16, 7], [4], [4], [1], 0, [8, 18], [18, 10]]
```

For example: the first row changes 0 to 1 in column `11` and column `17` and when the second row is 0, there is no change. The third row changes 0 to 1 in column `5` and column `6`..

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]...]])
```

This is my attempt:

```
for j in range (12):
    for i in range (len(newArr2[j])):
        rr=zero[j][newArr2[j][i]]=1
```

I am not sure how to solve it. Could you give me some recommendations? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that my answer may come as insightful.

```py
import numpy as np

zero =np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

newArr2 = [[11, 17], 0, [5, 6], [13], [4], [16, 7], [4], [4], [1], 0, [8, 18], [18, 10]]

# zero = zero.reshape(1,-1)

for i in newArr2:
    if i != 0:
        if type(i) == list:
            for x in i:
                zero[newArr2.index(i), x-1] = 1
        if type(i) == int:
            zero[newArr2.index(i), i-1] = 1
        
print(zero)
```

Comment: @starwinwin I am deeply thankful for your consideration. Nonetheless, I wish to inquire about whether you missed the fact that this site allows only the verification of one question. If that is true, please make sure to accept zoriana's question for he was the first to answer, and please have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
for i, x in enumerate(newArr2):
    if x==0:
        continue
    for j in x:
        zero[i][j-1]=1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).